# Not able to connect with my SP2013 Application

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I've created a new webApp in SP2013, when I dont use header name it goes fine by its default name and i am able to access it but when I use header name...it dont accept my credentials even I am login as a administrator.

I've already setup a New Host Entry in DNS.

Don't know what is wrong :(

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to reach the web application from the server?

Comment: ya..i m in the server itself.

Comment: did you disable the loopback check? also try from pc.

Comment: What Waqas said. However, dont disable the loopback check on a production environment. Try to access the site from computer.